# Add a fragment and release back stack fragments in one action in Android

Tags: android, fragmentmanager

How can I add a fragment and release all the back stack in Android under one action?

I've tried:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

Then to add my new fragment:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss(); 
    // or 
    fragmentTransaction.commit(); // i tried both of them
```

But I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use ft.addToBackStack(null) to avoid fragment back stack**

**eg :-**

```
SignUpAsFragment signUpAsFragment=new SignUpAsFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.user_signUp_frag_container,signUpAsFragment); // container is your FrameLayout container
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
```